# MySQL IFs and JOINs are generating redundant rows in SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
  `foo` - which contains information about an incident and

`bar` - which contains information about whether SLA's were met for each incident.

Each incident in `foo` will have either 1 or 2 corresponding rows in `bar`, depending on the type of incident.

I want to create a master view of each incident in `foo`, with a column for whether each type of SLA was met from `bar`.  I am using `IF` in subqueries to identify the type of SLA.
Expected output is:

```
|  ID  |  NAME      |   Thing1    |  Thing2 |   Response  |  Resolution  |
__________________________________________________________________________
| 11111| John       |  apple      | 12      |   Met       | Missed       |
| 33333| Sean       |  grape      |5        |             | Missed       |
```

I am getting 4 rows per incident for a result, when I only want one.

[Here's a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tjS8ofCiGbwBLSJvNZWncA/2)

Here's the last version of the SELECT statement I tried, and it returns 4 rows per ID:

```
SELECT foo.id
    , foo.name
    , foo.thing1
    , foo.thing2
    , x.Response
    , y.Resolution

FROM foo 

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT foo.id
    , IF (bar.svttitle LIKE "Response", bar.measurement_status, "") AS "Response"
    FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
           ) AS x ON foo.id = x.id 

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT foo.id
    , IF (bar.svttitle LIKE "Resolution", bar.measurement_status, "") AS "Resolution"
    FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
            ) AS y ON foo.id = y.id ;
```

I have tried this without subqueries and I have also tried adding additional join conditions to the subqueries on `bar`.  Neither have eliminated the duplicates.
Executing one of the subqueries by itself yields duplicate rows, so I am assuming that there's an issue with the `IF`, but I don't know of a different way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Plz share the expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove the `IF` and replace it with a `WHERE` on both subqueries, I get the expected results:

```
SELECT foo.id
    , foo.name
    , foo.thing1
    , foo.thing2
    , x.Response
    , y.Resolution

FROM foo 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT foo.id
    , bar.measurement_status AS "Response"
    FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
    WHERE bar.svttitle LIKE "Response"
           ) AS x ON foo.id = x.id 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT foo.id
    , bar.measurement_status AS "Resolution"
    FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
    WHERE bar.svttitle LIKE "Resolution"
            ) AS y ON foo.id = y.id ;
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tjS8ofCiGbwBLSJvNZWncA/3)

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to accept it